# Firefox nsITransactionListener, preventing willDo/didDo from happening

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpcom

I am listening to nsIHTMLEditor transactionManager and trying to prevent the contenteditable from doing some things that I want to dissalow:

```
let transactionManager = {
   didDo: (aManager, aTransaction, aDoResult) => {},
   willDo: function (aManager, aTransaction) {}
   ...
}

nsIHTMLEditor.transactionManager.AddListener(transactionManager);
```

Is there a way to prevent that transaction from being made, something like `event.preventDefault`. I can use `aTransaction.undoTransaction();` but does not work for willMerge and seems unperformant.

Thank you.

**Edit**

Thanks the nmaier answer in order to prevent a transaction you need to `return true`. However, on my current Firefox, 29.1, returning true crashes Firefox. Manage to get by this by throwing an error:

```
willDo: function (aManager, aTransaction) {
  throw Components.Exception("Error message");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`willDo`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/7586c29906b5/editor/txmgr/idl/nsITransactionListener.idl#l19) returns a `boolean`, which when `true` will interrupt the transaction.

When implemented in javascript without returning anything, it will return `undefined` which will be coerced into `false`, and that's why your code is working in the first place.
So just return `true` from `willDo` if you want to prevent the transaction.